# How to iterate through an Array value of a Dataframe?

Tags: apache-spark-sql, pyspark

I have a Pyspark dataframe that looks like this

```
>>> df1.show(1,False)
+---------------------------+
|col1                       |
+---------------------------+
|[this, is, a, sample, text]| => Not a fixed array elements
+---------------------------+
```

And a lookup table/df like this

```
>>> lookup.show()
+------+
|lookup|
+------+
|  this|
|    is|
|     a|
|sample|
+------+
```

For each row, each array element of the `df1` I need to do a look up in `lookup` dataframe and return true or false `[T,T,T,T,F]`

How can I loop through `df1`?

Comment: Please post your expected output.

Comment: I am looking for the approach, not a specific answer.  But I have updated my question to provide more clarity.

Comment: @Bala it depends on your Spark version (2.40+ or less) and how large is the lookup dataframe.

Comment: @jxc Spark 2.3.

Comment: then you probably need a udf. you might try `pos_explode` and then left_join, but explode is often expensive especially when your df has many columns.

Comment: I thought `explode` could help but the source df has couple of similar array columns and all of them requires a look up which makes it a very very expensive and it has 100+ million rows.